# Select messages from non-banned users

Tags: sequelize.js

```
CREATE TABLE msg (usr INTEGER, txt TEXT);
CREATE TABLE ban (usr INTEGER);
SELECT * FROM msg WHERE (msg.usr NOT IN (SELECT usr FROM ban));
```

This one-liner in plain SQL will select everything from `msg` if `msg.usr` is not found in `ban`. I have [Sequelize query docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/docs/querying/) open, but cannot find what is the Sequelize way of doing this?

Here, I have been able to get messages from banned users, but cannot invert the result:

```
var Msg = sequelize.define('Msg', {
    usr: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true },
    txt: Sequelize.STRING
}, {
    tableName: 'msg'
});

var Ban = sequelize.define('Ban', {
}, {
    tableName: 'ban'
});

Msg.hasMany(Ban);
Ban.belongsTo(Msg);

Msg.findAll({
    include: [{
            model: Ban,
            where: { MsgUsr: {$ne: null} }
        }]
}).then((a)=>{
    a.forEach((row)=>{
        let ban = '-'
        if(row.Bans[0]) ban = row.Bans[0].id
        console.log(row.usr, row.txt, ban)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The way is to write a raw SQL query, **@mhansen** (library maintainer) told.

[image]